# prevent slick slider to go backwards when autoplay is set to true and infinite is set to false

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

I have a slick slider with a navigation; slides are divided by decades (1935, 1940, etc)
those are the options of the slider:

```
this.slick_options = {
            infinite: false,
            speed: 300,
            autoplay: this.device === 'desktop',
            autoplaySpeed:1500,
            slidesToShow: 1,
            centerMode: true,
            variableWidth: true,
            arrows: true,
            useTransform: true,
            touchMove: false,
            pauseOnHover: false,
            responsive: [
                {
                    breakpoint: 1023,
                    settings: {
                        centerMode: false
                    }
                }
            ],
            swipe: this.device !== 'accessible'
        };
```

When a user click on a specific decade, this is what happen:

```
// navigation action
        self.$el.find('[data-gallery-toggle]').on('click', function() {
            let slider = self.$el.find('.gallery-content');
            let decade = $(this).data('gallery-toggle');
            let index = $(`[data-decade=${decade}]:first`).data('slick-index');
            slider[0].slick.slickGoTo(index);
            slider.slick('slickPlay');
        });
```

I also set some events:

```
_initSlick() {
        let self = this;

        self.$el.find('.gallery-content')
            .on('init', (event, slick) => {
                if(self.device === 'desktop') {
                    self.slidesLength = $('.slick-slide').length;
                    slick.$slides.on('click','.post-thumbnail', () => slick.$slider.slick('slickPause'))
                }
            })
            .on('afterChange', (event, slick, currentSlide,nextSlide) => {
                let decade = $(slick.$slides[slick.slickCurrentSlide()]).data('decade');
                let selectedNavigationElement = self.decadesNavigation.filter(`[data-gallery-toggle="${decade}"]`);
                self._switchClass(selectedNavigationElement);

                 if(self.device === 'desktop' && currentSlide === self.slidesLength - 1) {
                    slick.$slider.slick('slickPause');
                }

            }).slick(this.slick_options);

        // navigation action
        self.$el.find('[data-gallery-toggle]').on('click', function() {
            let slider = self.$el.find('.gallery-content');
            let decade = $(this).data('gallery-toggle');
            let index = $(`[data-decade=${decade}]:first`).data('slick-index');
            slider[0].slick.slickGoTo(index);
            slider.slick('slickPlay');
        });
    }
```

As you can see, autoplay is set ot true and infinite is set to false, when the user reach the last slide (afterchenge event) the slider is paused.

Also when a user click on one of the images, the slider is paused, when the user click on decades, the slider starts again

The problem is that when I click on one of the decades, sometimes the slider go back and not forward. I mean: if I am on the last slide and click on a previous decade, why the slider go back and not forward?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've found a solution; basically I've extendend the base option of slick:

```
changeDir: true
```

and then in the AutoplayIterator:

```
Slick.prototype.autoPlayIterator = function () {

        var _ = this;

        if (_.options.infinite === false) {

            if (_.direction === 1) {
//here I make the change
                if ((_.currentSlide + 1) === _.slideCount - 1 && _.options.changeDir)  {
                    _.direction = 0;
                }

                _.slideHandler(_.currentSlide + _.options.slidesToScroll);

            } else {
                if ((_.currentSlide - 1 === 0)) {

                    _.direction = 1;

                }

                _.slideHandler(_.currentSlide - _.options.slidesToScroll);

            }

        } else {

            _.slideHandler(_.currentSlide + _.options.slidesToScroll);

        }

    };
```

and in the index.js I simply set the new option chengeDir to false

Seems to work now